# Error: spawn EACCESS node-webkit ffmpeg with fluent-ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, node-webkit

I'm doing a nodewebkit app and trying to bundle ffmpeg inside so the user doesn't have to have ffmpeg installed on their system.

EACCESS has to do with rights running the code. I tried a `chmod -R ug+rw ffmpegFolder` to no avail.

I downloaded the osx binaries from here: https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/ I'm assuming these are compiled but I could be wrong?
I am bundling the extracted ffmpeg folder into the root of my `.nw`, which,  extracted looks like this:

[image: the .nw folder structure]

This part has to do with `fluent-ffmpeg`.
It has this method called `setFfmpegPath(path)` which tells fluent-ffmpeg to use a FFMPEG you provide.
I get the `fs.realpath` to ffmpeg-2.5.4 and use that.
Using ./ffmpeg-2.5.4 or /ffmpeg-2.5.4 or ffmpeg-2.5.4 just gives a spawn ENOENT error which I've read, means not found.
If I remove `setFfmepgPath` from my fluent-ffmpeg command it works fine using my system ffmpeg.

I feel I'm on the right track with the `spawn EACCESS` error. How to make it play nice though?

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace?

Comment: I got it to work.
It probably helps if use the build version of ffpmeg... Turns out I decided not to use the binary from evermeet for whatever reason - they are the ones that work though! 
I put the executable binary in the root.
The following works when the app is .nw and when packaged into a .app.
When it's time to call fluent-ffmpeg:
I get the path to ffmpeg binary: process.cwd()+'/ffmpeg'
I then do a fs.chmod(pp, '777', function(), inside the callback I do the fluent-ffmpeg command and setFfmpegPath to that same path
Yey!